# Return first match only with regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to extract a version number from a string using regular expression. The version number is in the format "D.D.Dc", where 'D' are digits (can be one or more instances) and 'c' is an optional alphabet character, surrounded by white spaces on either side.

The string I want to extract it from is something like:

```
FOO 5.1.7d BAR 5.0.2 2019/06/18
```

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
\s(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])?\s
```

Below is the the code I'm using.

```
static regex FWVersionFormat{ R"(\s(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])?\s)" }; 

auto matches = cmatch{};
if (regex_search(strVersion.c_str(), matches, FWVersionFormat))
{
    int maj = 0, min = 0, maint = 0, build = 0;
    if (!matches[1].str().empty()) maj = strtol(matches[1].str().c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    if (!matches[2].str().empty()) min = strtol(matches[2].str().c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    if (!matches[3].str().empty()) maint = strtol(matches[3].str().c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    if (!matches[4].str().empty()) build = matches[4].str().c_str()[0] - ('a' - 1);
    return{ maj, min, maint, build };
}
```

This works fine if there is only one match in the version string but the issue is that the regex_search() is putting the second instance of the version into the matches ("5.0.2").

I want to be able to only extract the first match. Is there any way to do this using regex?

Comment: Try adding a negative lookahead to prevent being followed by a digit https://regex101.com/r/x6Cnr6/1 `(\s(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])?\s(?!\d))`

Comment: Unable to reproduce with g++/libstdc++ 7.4.0. It matches `5.1.7d` from that string.

Comment: Also, why are you using `std::cmatch` instead of `std::smatch` and `std::strtol()` instead of `std::stoi()`, which works directly with `std::string` so you don't have to convert to a C style string? It'd make your code a lot cleaner and simpler... `maj = std::stoi(matches[1].str());` etc.

Comment: @Shawn I think OP only needs the first match which can be found just by getting the first instance of the cmatch??

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks - that seems do what I need.

Comment: @Minato `std::cmatch` is used when matching against C style strings, `std::smatch` when matching against `std::string`. OP has the latter but is converting them to the former first for some reason.

Comment: @Shawn I agree, that code isn't the cleanest. I can clean it up with your suggestions.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so I don't know if they have implemented regex_search differently to G++. But for me, it's only adding the second matching sequence to the "matches". 
The online regex tester I'm using matches both.

Comment: @ChrisJ If you only want the first match and you only need a single capturing group, you might also try `^.*?(\s\d+\.\d+\.\d+[a-zA-Z]?\s)` https://regex101.com/r/oH8D8X/1

Comment: You get the first match - https://ideone.com/ffLr2r

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems to work slightly different in different compilers, as Shawn above said it was fine for him using G++, but not for me in Visual Studio.

Comment: Notice that `'a'`-`''z'` is not guarantied to be contiguous (as with [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC))

Comment: Work as expected [here](https://ideone.com/Qfol2b).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, as I said above it seems to work in some compilers fine (G++, IDEONE) but not with Visual Studio for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @TheFourthBird for the answer.

I changed my regular expression to include a negative lookahead at the end so the search stops at the first matching instance.

```
\s(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])?\s(?!\d)
```